# How to resolve the error while executing top command using node child_process.exec?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, shell, child-process

I am trying to execute a bunch of bash commands using node.js. I used child_process.exec to execute the commands.

```
var child_process = require('child_process');
child_process.exec("ps -p $(lsof -ti tcp:8088) o pid=,comm=",function(err,stdout, stderr){
    if(err){
            console.log('error',err);
            return;
    }
    console.log('stdout', stdout);
});
```

This will list the process id running in the port 8088 along with name. In the similar way when i try to execute top command with a process id to check cpu and memory utilization. I am facing an error.

```
var execTop = function(pid){
        child_process.exec("top -p 12769", function(err, stdout, stderr){
                if(err){
                        console.log('error',err);
                        return;
                }
                console.log("top output",stdout);
        })
}
```

I couldn't find much resource online to clarify this issue. The actual error is

```
error { [Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c top -p 12769
top: failed tty get
]
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd: '/bin/sh -c top -p 12769' }
```

I appreciate the possible solutions suggested. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to run `top` like this, you need to run in it "Batch Mode", like:

```
top -b -n 1 -p 12345
```

This is because `top` is usually meant to be an interactive command and wants to have an actual terminal to write to.  You might want to consider using something like `ps u -p 12345` for more concise output.

Comment: This top command in batch mode works perfectly. And is it possible to list only %Cpu & %Mem columns and discard rest of the columns with this command?

Answer (score 3):

as Grisha suggested, use the 'Batch Mode' and if only cpu and memory is needed, for default top output I'd use something like:

```
top -b -n 1 -p 12345 | awk '{if(NR>7)print $9,$10}'
```